# Cordova plugin file

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins, windows-8.1

I am developing Cordova app for windows 8.1 platform as my target.
I am using **cordova-plugin-file** plugin, and my clobber cordova.file is set as undefined.
However I can get the plugin when I call require:

var p = cordova.require("cordova-plugin-file.FileProxy");
p.requestAllPaths(function(data){ console.log(data);});

Something overrides the object? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is a known bug. That's what I got from ASFs JIRA on my bug report: 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9986

- Also I've changed window.file to cordova.file at the question.